# Change amount of visible slides for tablet & mobile devices

Tags: slider, bxslider

I'm using bxslider and I want to make only one slide appear when on tablet and mobile (768px and down), but when above 768px then I'd like 6+ slides to appear. Can anyone help me out with this please?

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
captions: true,
speed: 900,
pause: 7000,
startSlide: 0,
infiniteLoop: true,
auto: true,
video: true,
touchEnabled: false,
pager: false,

});
});

if ( $(window).width() < 768) {
var myslider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    ...
    maxSlides       : 1,
});  
}

else {
var myslider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    ...
    maxSlides       : 4,
});
}
</script>
```

If anyone could help that would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove the first bxSlider() instance, you call it only inside of the conditions:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(function(){
        if( $(window).width() < 768) {
            $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                captions: true,
                speed: 900,
                pause: 7000,
                startSlide: 0,
                infiniteLoop: true,
                auto: true,
                video: true,
                touchEnabled: false,
                pager: false,
                maxSlides: 1
            }); 
        } else {
            $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                captions: true,
                speed: 900,
                pause: 7000,
                startSlide: 0,
                infiniteLoop: true,
                auto: true,
                video: true,
                touchEnabled: false,
                pager: false,
                maxSlides: 4
            });
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, that didn't seem to work though. I've currently got two slides that are being pulled through from my ACF Repeater (WordPress) and both slides are still showing. The only impact it made was that the arrows to go between slides seemed to disappear.